# Convert image data url to blob using angular 4 or more?

Tags: angular, npm

I found "blob-util" package for angularjs which converts data URL to blob.But I am not sure whether it works for higher versions.Can anyone suggest how to achieve the same??

Comment: is this what you want?[link](https://hshno.de/SktUOOuuf)

Comment: Have you tried using the library you mentioned? I see no reason why it wouldn;t work for angular 4+...